# The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.dartargument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: function, flutter, build

### Situation:

I have a function in the simple class (not stateful or stateless) but that function is called in the first Screen of the stateful widget, inside the function I have used `Navigator.push` to go to the second screen of the stateful widget.

### Code:

**Funtion Code**

```
containerAdder(initialI) {
    List<Widget> listViewContainer = List();

    for (var j = 0; j < mainListAllPlantDetailsList1.length; j++) {
      if (tabsText[initialI] == mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[j].ca) {
        listViewContainer.add(
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context, **(MENTIONED ERROR GIVES OVERHERE )**
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ParticularPlant2()),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
                height: 320,
                width: 200,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 50, 20, 20),
                        height: 150,
                        width: 180,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.lightGreen,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
                            bottomEnd: Radius.circular(70),
                            topEnd: Radius.circular(70),
                            topStart: Radius.circular(70),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[j].ca),
                            Text(mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[j].pN),
                            Text(mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[j].pr.toString()),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    return listViewContainer;
  }
```

There are two other stateful widgets on two other screens whereas in first screen I have called this function.

### Question:

Help me to understand why does the mentioned error occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you calling the function??

Comment: objectnameofclass.functionname(); in another screen of statful widget

Comment: Why don't you pass context as argument in the function? Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, did not work

Comment: Aman, I have posted the answer please review it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets pass the context to your function to make it work:

```
containerAdder(initialI, BuildContext context) { 
    // Your all of the codes
}
```

Now, call the containerAdder like:

```
objectName.containerAdder(intialI, context);
```

Comment: It worked thanks, Why does this kind of error happens?

Comment: Because it is normal class as you said... It does not know anything about context. Pure **dart** you can say. As we passed the context of the stateful widget as argument, it now take `context` as a object of class `BuildContext`. It can proceed forward as expected...